# Web application deployed in Vagrant works in browser but authentication doesn't work in REST client

Tags: java, spring, rest, vagrant, weblogic

I have a web application that works fine locally both in browser and in my java applet that access it as a REST API.

When I deploy the same application in a vagrant VM, I'm able to access it via browser, run in debug mode and make a remote deploy using maven plugin; but I am not able to authenticate using my REST Client.

I'm getting the following response:

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.46) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity MAY include
>   relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
>   explained in section 11.

Here is my Vagrant File:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2223, id: 'ssh'
  config.vm.box = "weblogic-box"

  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vbguest.auto_update = true

  # workaround the vagrant 1.8.5 bug
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  # change memory size
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4000
    v.name = "vagrant-weblogic"
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end

  # Oracle port forwarding
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1521, host: 1522
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7001, host: 7001
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7002, host: 7002
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4000, host: 4000

  #use $ ssh -X -p 2222 to run graphical applications
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true

  # Provision everything on the first run
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/install.sh"

end
```

And my weblogic configuration:

```
import os

readTemplate(os.environ["WL_HOME"] + '/common/templates/wls/wls.jar')

cd('Servers/AdminServer')
set('ListenAddress','')
set('ListenPort', 7001)

cd('/')
cd('Security/base_domain/User/weblogic')
cmo.setPassword('welcome1')

setOption('OverwriteDomain', 'true')

writeDomain(os.environ["MW_HOME"] + '/user_projects/domains/my-domain')
closeTemplate()

exit()
```

Is there any Vagrant/Weblogic configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: would need a bit more info (Vagrantfile, weblogic config)

Comment: usually if you can access through browser from the host machine, it means the setup is correct, and it should work for a REST client

Comment: I agree with you, but it simply doesn't work. I updated with my VagrantFile and WLST file.

Comment: can you try `set('ListenAddress','0.0.0.0')` but normally this is more or less what its supposed to do (according to doc)

Comment: Frédéric, I just tested it using Advanced REST client chrome plugin, and the rest API is working, the problem is the authetication. It works locally, but not inside the vagrant VM.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it, the problem was that I was enforcing basic authentication when I was performing a custom authentication. Just followed the instructions in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/security/thin_client.html#understanding_basic_atn), and added the following configuration in the config.xml file.

```
</security-configuration>
.
.
.
     <enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
</security-configuration>
```